# Previous month query - Databricks

Tags: function, filter, databricks, databricks-sql, aws-databricks

I try to find a function where I can extract the result of the last month only
(for exemple if I launch the query in november, I want to display only the resultat of october)

There the result :
[image]

I dont know if I have to enter the function in my select or where clause

Thanks for you help!!
CHeers!

I tried the function month(date, -1)

I want to see all the result for the previous month

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the date and applying in the where clause.

Note that there may be more efficient options available.

Query to Use:

```
WHERE 
DATE_TRANSACTION BETWEEN 
trunc(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, dayofmonth(CURRENT_DATE)),'MM') 
AND 
date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, dayofmonth(CURRENT_DATE))
```

Explanation:

- CURRENT_DATE - Gives the current Date
- dayofmonth(CURRENT_DATE) - Gives the day part of current date.
- date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, dayofmonth(CURRENT_DATE)) - Gives the last day of previous month. Assume current_date is 2022-11-23, dayofmonth will give 23, when you subtract 23 days, it goes to the last day of previous month i.e. 2022-10-31.
- trunc(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, dayofmonth(CURRENT_DATE)),'MM') - Truncates date to first day of month.
- DATE_TRANSACTION  - between these two days.

[image]